How to make an API call inside AppWidgetProvider - Android
I have a widget that shows data
How to make an API call inside the widget class to update the data?

If by "API call" you mean something like calling a Web service, the AppWidgetProvider cannot really do that directly, due to its short lifespan. Instead, use WorkManager to kick off some work to get the data and update the app widget UI.
